# More simple PHP xpath query

Tags: php, xpath

My xpath query in PHP 7 to get DS Clock version: 5.0.0.2 from URL: https://www.dualitysoft.com/download.html#dsc is like this:

`"//th/b[text()[contains(.,'DS Clock')]]//parent::th//parent::tr//following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]"`

Can it be more simple? I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
"((//table[.//*[contains(.,'DS Clock ')]])[last()]//tr)[2]//td[1]"
```

Or this:

```
"//table//table//table//table[.//tr[@bgcolor="#8bc688"] and .//b[contains(.,'DS Clock ')]]//tr[2]/td[1]"
```

Comment: To only get the number, add `/text()[2]`

Comment: Right, I know, thanks. I just tried to give alternative XPath to the element the author is locating with his XPath but without the use of `parent::` etc.

Comment: Alternative version of parents: `"//th/b[text()[contains(.,'DS Clock')]]//..//..//following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]"`

Comment: OK.  I'm getting the `table` parent based on unique children elements and then getting the child `tr` and `td` nodes

Comment: So far I get this: `"//tr[contains(.//b, 'DS Clock')]//following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]"` and with Reynadan tip final version: `"//tr[contains(.//b, 'DS Clock')]//following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]/text()[2]"`

Comment: OK, nice solution too